# User can scale website with pinch on android 4.3 even if I set user-scalable=no

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, mobile

I use the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

To remove the website scaling ability, but I user reported he can still sace the website in android 4.3, is something changed in 4.3 in regards with this meta tag?

Answer (score 1):

The user might have the have the option enabled that lets them override the pinch zoom settings.  Our guidance for web developers is not to stop the user from zooming on your content if they need too.

[image: Force enable zoom]